# Is this a crazy way to handle multi Validation types with IDataError and WPF?

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, styles

We are using the standard method for our controls to report broken BO rules. This is done via the interface IDataError in our BO’s and in XAML the control is bound to the BO’s property etc. This approach works OK. But we need to show 2 types of visuals in the UI depending on the type (or category if you like) of the invalidation error. If it’s a required field then we show a CueBanner (water mark) but for other types we change the colour of the controls boarder. In both scenarios we set the tool type of the error message.

The Problem with IDataError is that it doesn’t support a method/property to distinguish between error types.

The only way I can do that is by examining the error text, required field text must contain the key word “required”. The following approach doesn’t feel right but it’s the only way I can determine the type of error and then deal with it accordingly. All required field rules must have as part of the error text “required field”.
To make this all work I have created a custom dependency property called ErrorMessage. In my ResourceDictionary I have a Style.Trigger for Validation.HasError. In there I set my dependency properties value to the ErrorContent. Now when my dependency properties value changes I can examine the text and set the Validation.SetErrorTemplate( myControl, newErrorTemplate) to the template to suit the error type. I have to wire up a few events to the control such as lost and got focus to manage removing or adding the cueBanner template but the whole thing will work. It’s just that I’m not sure it’s the best way to do it.

PS. When I set the ErrorTemplate i’m doing this in code, thats building and adding it. Is there a way to point Validation.SetErrorTemplate to a static resource keeping in mind that I need to switch between at least 2 types?

Your thoughts please..

Answer (score 3):

Would it be possible to derive an interface IDataError that adds an extra property which is an enumeration of the error type. Then you could try and bind against it.

Comment: I don't think the extra property is accessible from the error-template. The DataContext of the ErrorTemplate is the Validation.Errors Collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with an (untested)approach that suffers a little bit of clarity, then you could do the following:
throw an exception instead of returning an string with the IDataErrorInfo Interface. In your ErrorTemplate, you can access the ValidationErrors (and the ValidationError.Exception Property).

Then, you use a DataTrigger on the Exception in combination with a converter, that checks for the right Exception-Type and return true or false. It should be enough to do the job.